# Pass another element to ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs, pass-by-reference

I want to create a list of items, which are simple clickable text. Each time you click on an item it tranforms to an input (textbox) and you can edit it. I have done this already. The only thing I am missing is to **set the focus on the input element** when I click on the item. My HTML code is the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span ng-if="!valueIsEditedForItem(item.id)">
    <a href="" ng-click="editValueForItem(item.id)">
      {{ item.value }}
    </a>
  </span>
  <span ng-if="valueIsEditedForItem(item.id)">
    <input ng-model="edited_value"
           ng-keyup="onValueInput($event, item.id, edited_value)"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

The `<a>` element and the `<input>` element are two different elements. So, my idea is to pass the input element somehow to the `ng-click="editValueForItem(item.id)`. It should look something like this:

```
<a href="" ng-click="editValueForItem(item.id, inputElement)">
  {{ item.value }}
</a>
```

Then I would be able to set the focus to the input element by doing this:

```
inputElement.focus();
```

I know that the `$event` variable holds the element of the event in `$event.target`. But my event is on `<a>` and not on `<input>`. **How can I reference the `<input>` element into `<a>`**?

---

**EDIT: Solution**

After reading solution suggestions from the answers, I finally implemented this by referencing by id:

***HTML***

```
<input id="{{'input' + item.id}}"
       ng-model="edited_value"
       ng-keyup="onInput($event, item.id, edited_value)"/>
```

***JS***

```
$scope.editValueForItem = function (itemId) {
  $scope.currentlyEditedItemId = itemId;

  // focus on the input element
  setTimeout(function () {
    var inputElement = document.getElementById("input" + itemId);
    if (inputElement) {
      inputElement.focus();
    }
  }, 0);
};
```

The `setTimeout` clause is necessary to give priority to the initialization of the element. If you remove it, then the `getElementById` command will return null, because the input element will not have been initialized yet.

However, the solution with creating my own directive would be a more proper option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight approach is to add some ref, e.g.:

```
<input ng-model="edited_value" editable="{{item.id}}"
       ng-keyup="onValueInput($event, item.id, edited_value)"/>
```

```js
// editValueForItem method
$timeout(() => angular.element(document.querySelector('[editable="' + itemId + '"]')).focus())
```

Another might be:

```
<input ng-model="edited_value" take-focus-on-init
       ng-keyup="onValueInput($event, item.id, edited_value)"/>
```

where `take-focus-on-init` is directive that focus element in link function.

Third one is to make directive:

```
<editable value="item.value"></editable>
```

with template:

```
<div ng-if="!inEditMode">{{item.value}}</div>
<div ng-if="inEditMode"><input ...</div>
```

here you can use simple `element.find('input').focus()`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to pass `$event` into function and find the input using `$event.target` :

```
<a href="" ng-click="editValueForItem($event)">
    {{ item.value }}
</a>
```

```js
editValueForItem = function($event) {
    let $target = angular.element($event.target);
    let nextInput = $target.parent().parent().find('input')[0];

    if (nextInput.length) {
        nextInput.focus();
    }
}
```